# How to install an older version of Java

Tags: apt, package-management, java, dpkg, downgrade

I updated my installation of the sun-java6-jdk package today to version 6.24-1build0.10.10.1 after being prompted by the update manager. However this now causes some compilation failures so I'd like to revert back to the previous version that I had installed.

I've tried using Synaptic but the 'Force Version' menu command is disabled.

I've tried the following command to install the previous version

`sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jdk=6.22-0ubuntu1~10.10`

But I'm not sure that I have the correct version:

```
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done 
E: Version ‘6.22-0ubuntu1~10.10’ for ‘sun-java6-jdk’ was not found
```

I've taken this version number from this changelog: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sun-java6/+changelog

Is this the correct way to install a previous version of a package? Have I got the correct version from the sun-java6 change log?

Comment: I usually just do `apt-get install sun-java6-jdk`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the correct way to downgrade a package, but you seem to have got the version number wrong....

apt-get install sun-java6-jdk=6.22-0ubuntu1~10.10 - won't work since there is no such package in the Package.gz list, that's why you got the error: Version ‘6.22-0ubuntu1~10.10’ for ‘sun-java6-jdk’ was not found.

Try this... 
`dpkg -r sun-java6-jdk` --- Removes the sun-java6-jdk

Download the .deb for your previous sun-java6-jdk version, you may already have this file in /var/cache/apt/archives --- use: `$ ls /var/cache/apt/archives/sun* -lash` in your terminal to find out whether you have an older version locally.

`apt-get install -d sun-java-jdk` / openjdk-6-jdk -- the -d will only download the file into your /var/cache/apt/arhives folder.

`dpkg -i --force-downgrade /var/cache/apt/archives/sun-java-jdk`(the version # that you have).

[Lock Version](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1354094) in Synaptic so ubuntu doesn't try to upgrade it again.
[Dpkg man](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/dpkg.1.html) page will also help explain things -- downgrade has a big warning label on it in the man pages, so take note you don't wreck your dependencies.
There is a post [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/52029/how-to-force-downgrade-of-packages-on-ubuntu-karmic) and [here](http://www.nickveenhof.be/blog/reverting-or-downgrade-php-53-52-ubuntu-lucid-lynx-1004) that explains downgrading.

Answer (score 0):

The way I got the older version of java was different. I used the command `$ sudo apt-get install default-jre`, so you should use that command as well. No extra repository is needed. If you DO use this command, I suggest removing the previous package you tried using by typing in `sudo apt-get remove sun-java6-jdk=6.22-0ubuntu1~10.10`. By now, you should have a working previous java version. The `default-jre` package uses the java version 1.7.0_91. I hope this answer will be of use to you.